# Why Is This Method With a Generic Parameter Failing When Being Called?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class:

```
public class Document<T> : IFormattable<string, Document<T>> where T : Info
{
    public Document(IList aList<T>) { ... }

    public string Format(IFormatter<string, Document<T>> formatter) { ... }
}
```

and a function in another class that takes a Document T:

```
public void Insert<T>(Document<T> document) where T : Info
{
    IFormatter<string, Document<ConcreteInfo>> formatter = new ConcreteFormatter();
    document.Format(formatter);
}
```

however the compiler complains with:

> The best overloaded method for Document.Format(IFormatter>) has some invalid arguments.

As far as I can see the Format method of Document takes an

```
IFormattable<string, Document<T>>
```

with a constraint of Info on T and that is what the variable formatter that is being passed in is.

Can anyone tell me what the issue is?

Comment: It's hard to tell you exactly without knowing more of your type hierarchy, but it sounds like you have a variance issue. You can start reading about this here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx (there are more articles linked from there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Insert` method creates an object that doesn't have a generic type parameter - `new ConcreteFormatter()` - so this cannot be used when the method and the `document.Format` call are expecting the type to vary on `T`.

You need something like this:

```
public void Insert<T>(Document<T> document) where T : Info
{
    IFormatter<string, Document<T>> formatter = new ConcreteFormatter<T>();
    document.Format(formatter);
}
```

Better yet:

```
public void Insert<T>(Document<T> document) where T : Info
{
    var formatter = new ConcreteFormatter<T>();
    document.Format(formatter);
}
```

Comment: @Jakub - `ConcreteFormatter` cannot implement `IFormatter<string, Document<T>>` without passing in `T` as `ConcreteFormatter<T>`. From the OP's code it was clear that `ConcreteFormatter` implemented `IFormatter<string, Document<ConcreteInfo>>` which is not castable to `IFormatter<string, Document<T>>`.

Answer (score 4):

What is the type of T when document.Format is being called? Or, what is the type of document?

If it's not ConcreteInfo, then you have a problem:

```
Document<OtherInfo> document = new Document<OtherInfo>();
IFormatter<string, Document<ConcreteInfo>> formatter = new ConcreteFormatter();
document.Format(formatter);
```

Format expects `IFormatter<string, Document<OtherInfo>>` but you're passing `IFormatter<string, Document<ConcreteInfo>>`